# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'creates')

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, discord.js

I am trying to check if mongodb has a value to run an event, I have the code

`if (guildSchema.events.channel.creates.enabled === false) {`

And in the database the path is events -> channel -> creates -> enabled

[image: https://prnt.sc/xnJIyZxjBz7_]

but when creating a channel it returns the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'creates')`

Code:

```
    const guildSchema = require('../../models/guildSchema');

    const data = await guildSchema.findOne({
        id: channel.guild.id
    });
    if (!data) {
        return;
    }
    if (data) {
        if (guildSchema.events.channel.creates.enabled === false) {
        // CODE
    } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `guildSchema.events.channel.creates.enabled` should be `data.events.channel.creates.enabled`

Comment: ah thank you, such a simple typo this fixed it